# Fill grid layout manager columns first then rows

Tags: android, kotlin, android-recyclerview, adapter, gridlayoutmanager

I have 7 elements (in a simplified manner here). How can I set grid layout to make a 2-column layout with the first 4 elements on the column1 and the rest elemnts on the column2.
Like this

```
   1   5
   2   6
   3   7
   4
```

I am using recycler view with GridLayout

```
val itemDecoration = ItemOffsetDecoration(8)
recycler_view.layoutManager = GridLayoutManager(context, 2)
recycler_view.adapter = MyAdapter(context, items)
recycler_view.addItemDecoration(itemDecoration)
```

Comment: may be using a custom layout manager

Comment: @Raghunandan Can you please explain more, if possible please share any examples.

Comment: Something like : 

      public void onBindViewHolder(final BadgeViewHolder holder, int position) {
        // Pair -> left column
        if (position % 2 == 0 ){
            itemdecorator.get(position);
        }else{
            int computePosition = position = offset + (position / 2) - 1;
            itemdecorator.get(position);
        }


Where offset is compute thx to the size of your datastructure & the number of row in your grid layout manager (size / nbrOfRow rounded to upper value).

Comment: Did you find a solution?

Comment: @AyxanHaqverdili Not yet.

Answer (score 0):

I think you can achieve your goal by adding a suitable binding method. You can use if statements in the method to bind data to the holders correctly based on the holders position.